# Charge ThinkPad X1 Yoga Gen 2 with a Xiaomi 65W USB-C GaN charger

Tags: charger

Is it safe to charge a [ThinkPad X1 Yoga Gen 2](https://www.lenovo.com/de/de/p/laptops/thinkpad/thinkpadx1/x1-yoga-2nd-generation/22tp2txx12y) with a Xiaomi **[65W USB-C GaN](https://www.mi.com/de/product/mi-65w-fast-charger-with-gan-tech/)** charger?

Comment: It will either charge, or it won't. It's unlikely the charger would explode.

Comment: Why wouldn’t it be?

Answer (score 2):

See:   [GAN charger](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-X-Series-Laptops/120w-GaN-SiC-USB-C-Charger-65W-Lenovo-X1-Yoga-Gen4-OK/m-p/5037657?page=1)

> PD is limited at 100W, which is why your laptop is charging at that
> rate rather than 120W

It is OK to try the charger and see how it works for you. It is most unlikely to do any damage.

The charger is not on the ThinkPad Yoga compatibility list, so you need to understand the limitations if you use it.

Although your model is no longer current, the charger you are intending to use is not supported by Lenovo.